# Inherit from Dictionary or create my own class with a dictionary

Tags: c#, inheritance

I'm working C# on an exercise that is it very strange.

I have these three classes.

```
public abstract BaseClass<T> Where T : BaseClass<T>

public class Class1

public class Class2 : BaseClass<Class2>
```

On the exercise there is this strange declaration:

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary { [class1] = class1, [class2] = class2 };
```

I think that here, `Dictionary` is a shortcut for `Dictionary<object, object>`
; so I have added this class to the project:

```
public class Dictionary : Dictionary<object, object>
```

But I'm not sure if it is a good idea to inherit from Dictionary into a production environment (where I'm going to apply what I have learned).

So, I have decided to change the declaration on my custom dictionary class with this:

```
public class Dictionary
{
    Dictionary<object, object> dictionary = new Dictionary<object, object>();

    public object this[object index]
    {
        get
        {
            return dictionary[index];
        }

        set
        {
            dictionary[index] = value;
        }
    }

    public bool ContainsKey(object key)
    {
        return dictionary.ContainsKey(key);
    }
}
```

Which one is better?

By the way, I have to use `ContainsKey` in the exercise.

I can't modify the exercise. I have to create the classes that make it compiles and works (do whatever it does).

Comment: The generic parameters for `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` are inferred here (they depend on the types of those `class1` and `class2` variables - for example, if those are `Class1` objects then the compiler is smart enough to figure out that you need a `Dictionary<Class1, Class1>`). There should be no need for a custom `Dictionary` class.

Comment: @PieterWitvoet I can't modify the exercise. I have to create the classes that make it compiles and works (do whatever it does). And also, the keys could be from different types.

Comment: Hm, I thought constructor type inference might've been added, but apparently not, my bad, I should've checked that. So you do have to create your own `Dictionary` class. What's the purpose of this exercise? Inheriting from dictionaries or other collections is often not the best thing to do, unless you're building a custom collection class, but that's rare.

Comment: The purpose of this exercise is **to know what decisions I take** when I find such kind of problems: a class called dictionary with keys of any type (and values also) and with a method that search of a key in the class (`ContainsKey` method).

Comment: That doesn't look like a realistic scenario to me: you've been given code that doesn't compile, but you're not allowed to modify it? The most sane solution here would be to change `new Dictionary` to `new Dictionary<object, object>`, but you're not allowed to do that, so you have to create a `Dictionary` class. Composition is often better than inheritance, but inheriting from `Dictionary<object, object>` requires almost no code and quickly gets this hack-job done so it might be more economical in this particular case. Just be sure to add a comment about how it *should* be solved.

Comment: Another note: a `Dictionary<object, object>` is pretty much throwing away any type-safety/convenience that using a generic collection gives you, and it doesn't help in documenting purpose. Using a common base class or interface for values is a good idea. And for keys, you'll want to avoid using mutable types (modifying a key breaks lookup), so using `object` as `TKey` is a bad idea. Finally, using objects as keys for themselves is odd, as the given code does. Strange exercise indeed. My decision would be to talk to the person that gave me this assignment. ;)

Comment: Yes, it is a very strange exercise but I think they want to check what I do with such kind of code. I have added a comment telling all we have talked about it here.

Comment: @VansFannel take into consideration that the purpose of this exercise *may* be to see if you ask for clarification